# p7b certificate has been issued by DigiCertificate but unable to figure out the OID object identifier of the p7b certificate

Tags: signtool, p7b

I have tried this signtool.exe sign /p7 C:\CertificateName.p7  /p7ce Embedded /p7co  "C:\bin\xx*.dll" but i feel like OID value is wrong hence the error is
**SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.**

Can anyone help me to figure out the OID value of the P7b Certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the p7b certificate provided by Digi Certificate.
using the below website i was able to export the pfx certificate.

https://www.digicert.com/kb/util/pfx-certificate-management-utility-import-export-instructions.htm

For downloading the pfx file you need to know the csr password which has been created before.
if its your first time applying and downloading the DigiCertificate then you need to creat the CSR and use its password as pfx password of the certificate.